# Restar minutos a date()

Tags: php

Estoy intentando restar 15 minutos a `date()` de la siguiente forma, pero no funciona, el output es algo similar a 1593076260

```html
$nowHour = date("H:i");
$nowHour = strtotime('-15 minute', strtotime($nowHour));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías también usar `DateTime` para esto.

Por ejemplo, puedes crear un objeto directamente con la hora de *hace 15 minutos*:

```
$mPastDate = new DateTime("15 minutes ago");
echo  $mPastDate->format("H:i");
```

**Salida:**

```
12:45
```

Si, de todos modos quieres hacerlo con `strtotime`, no tienes necesidad de un doble uso de la función, puedes simplificar así:

```
$mPastTime = strtotime('-15 minutes');
echo date('H:i', $mPastTime);
```

**PD:**

En `DateTime` también funciona la notación `- valor`, por ejemplo:

```
$mPastDate = new DateTime("-15 minutes");
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontré la solución añadiendo esta linea, que transforma a `date()`

```html
$nowHour = date("H:i");
$nowHour = strtotime('-15 minute', strtotime($nowHour));
$nowHour = date('H:i', $nowHour);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no trabajas con `DateTime`? Es una clase más completa y permite hacer este tipo de cosas con mayor simplicidad.